# Why is Matplotlib.pyplot not working in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I tried running simple plotting code in Visual Studio Code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

This keeps coming up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\sony\PycharmProjects\ip project\plot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\sony\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import _api, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\sony\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "C:\Users\sony\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib\fontconfig_pattern.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pyparsing import (Literal, ZeroOrMore, Optional, Regex, StringEnd,
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyparsing'
```

I tried installing pyparsing and this came up:

```
    PS C:\Users\sony\OneDrive\Desktop\VSC Python Projects> pip install pyparsing
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages (2.4.7)
WARNING: Error parsing requirements for iniconfig: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\program files\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\iniconfig-1.1.1.dist-info\\METADATA'
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely caused by a version mismatch between matplotlib and pyparsing.

Google matplotlibs dependencies for your installed version (you can see the version by running `pip freeze`) and look at which version they require for pyparsing. Probably it is something like `>= 2.3.1`. Try to uninstall your pyparsing with `pip uninstall pyparsing` and install exactly the version that is on the right of the >=. In my example `pip install pyparsing==2.3.1`.

When I had the problem my pyparsing was version 3.x.x which was probably to new for matplotlib, meaning that their dependencies are outdated. Just use exactly the version they require and you should be good.